# AttributeError: __getitem__ in Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror

I'm trying to open a text file called filteredApps.txt which contains "app1.ear, app2.ear, app3.ear, app4.ear" as new lines, pass it to a list and then compare it to another list. Then finally call the deploy function in the main() method but I get  AttributeError: **getitem** in the line hightlighted below on the code:

```
appNames = ['/opt/app1.ear', '/opt/app2.ear', '/opt/app3.ear', '/opt/app4.ear']

def filteredApps():
    filteredAppsList = []
    appToDeploy = open("filteredApps.txt","r")
    for deploy in appToDeploy:   #Code breaks here
        filteredAppsList.append(deploy)
    return map(str.strip, filteredAppsList)

def main():
    finalListToDeploy = []
    listToDeploy = filteredApps() #Code breaks here as well

    for paths in appNames:
        for apps in listToDeploy:
            if apps in paths:
                finalListToDeploy.append(apps)
    deployApplication(finalListToDeploy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What does *Code breaks here*, mean? What error do you get?

Comment: Please post the complete trace back.

Comment: Where is `deployApplication` defined?

Comment: `appToDeploy = open("filteredApps.txt","r")` not the right way to do it

Comment: I'm just highlighting which lines jenkins says the error comes from. The code breaks before the deployApplication() is called so it is not relevant for this question

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: The error I get when the code runs is is ** AttributeError: __getitem__**

Comment: Has Jenkins a "debug mode" to make errors more verbose?

Comment: My desired output is the finalListToDeploy=[/opt/app1.ear', '/opt/app2.ear', '/opt/app3.ear', '/opt/app4.ear] which will be used by the deployApplication()

Comment: What information contains filteredApps.txt? Only lines with names?

Comment: replace `listToDeploy = filteredApps()` with `listToDeploy = list(filteredApps())`

Comment: replace `finalListToDeploy.append(apps)` with `finalListToDeploy.append(paths)` since you need the paths and not the file names

Comment: cat filteredApps.txt
app1.ear
app2.ear
app3.ear
app4.ear

Comment: Change this `appToDeploy = open("filteredApps.txt","r")` to `with open("list.txt","r") as appToDeploy:`

Comment: @Sizwe see the answer I posted below, with all the changes I suggested here?

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comments:

filteredApps.txt:

```
app1
app2
app3
app4
```

**Hence**:

```
appNames = ['/opt/app1.ear', '/opt/app2.ear', '/opt/app3.ear', '/opt/app4.ear']

def filteredApps():
    filteredAppsList = []
    with open("filteredApps.txt","r") as appToDeploy:
      for apptodeploy in appToDeploy:
          # print(apptodeploy)
          filteredAppsList.append(apptodeploy)
    return map(str.strip, filteredAppsList)

def main():
    finalListToDeploy = []
    listToDeploy = list(filteredApps())
    for paths in appNames:
        for apps in listToDeploy:
            if apps in paths:
                # print(paths)
                finalListToDeploy.append(paths)
    return finalListToDeploy
    # deployApplication(finalListToDeploy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(main())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['/opt/app1.ear', '/opt/app2.ear', '/opt/app3.ear', '/opt/app4.ear']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reading the file before looping over the data

```
 appToDeploy = open("filteredApps.txt","r") 
 contents = appToDeploy.readlines()
 appToDeploy.close()

 for deploy in contents:     
     filteredAppsList.append(deploy)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm busy testing it now. Give me a sec

Comment: @Sizwe how's it going? Any advances?

Comment: 09:53:05 Traceback (innermost last):
09:53:05   File "<string>", line 129, in ?
09:53:05   File "/home/jenkins/workspace/sizwe_deploy/bin/../deploy/deployApplication.py", line 350, in main

09:53:05   File "/home/jenkins/workspace/sizwe_deploy/bin/../deploy/deployApplication.py", line 329, in filteredApps

09:53:05 AttributeError: instance of 'org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction' has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @Sizwe that's got something to do with  your map(str.strip, filteredAppsList)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use open as follow:

```
import io
from io import open
with open('tfilteredApps.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file :    
    for deploy in file :
        filteredAppsList.append(deploy)
```

But if you have all app name in one line it gonna be like this with pickle module:

```
import pickle
with open('tfilteredApps.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file :
    word = pickle.load(file)
filteredAppsList = word.split(' ')
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try it soon and give feedback